# Download large file from HTTP with resume/retry support in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, http, file-io, web

How to implement downloading a large file (~500MB) from HTTP in my application? I want to support automatic resume/retry, so that when connection is disconnected, my application can try to reconnect to get the file and avoid re-downloading the downloaded part, if possible (I know, this depends on the server as well).

This is similar to the behaviour in download managers and some browsers.

Comment: Something you should know is that whether a download can be resumed or not is determined by the server

Comment: @RanhiruCooray Yes, I am aware of that. My question is how to resume when the server allows it

Comment: You'll have to request the correct range yourself. Not even the new shiny `Http.Client` does this automatically: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/23/asp-net-web-api-and-http-byte-range-support.aspx  (Unless you find a dedicated file download library.)

Comment: @millimoose maybe I misunderstood something, but it seems like the link is about providing resume capability in servers?

Comment: @LouisRhys It describes both sides of the protocol, which either side must be aware of. I.e. you make a `Range` request, and either get a `Content-Range` response for the range you wanted, or you get a "normal" response which contains the whole resource. It's just an overview anyway, you'll have to hit up the HTTP spec or other articles about the topic too.

Answer (score 15):

You can implement downloading from a web-server in `C#` from scratch in one of the two ways:

1. Using the high-level APIs in System.Net such as `HttpWebRequest`, `HttpWebResponse`, `FtpWebRequest`, and other classes.
2. Using the low-level APIs in System.Net.Sockets such as `TcpClient`, `TcpListener` and Socket classes.

The advantage of using the first approach is that you typically don't have to worry about the low level plumbing such as preparing and interpreting HTTP headers and handling the proxies, authentication, caching etc. The high-level classes do this for you and hence I prefer this approach.

Using the first method, a typical code to prepare an HTTP request to download a file from a url will look something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
if (UseProxy)
{
    request.Proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyServer + ":" + ProxyPort.ToString());
    if (ProxyUsername.Length > 0)
        request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyUsername, ProxyPassword);
}
//HttpWebRequest hrequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
//hrequest.AddRange(BytesRead); ::TODO: Work on this
if (BytesRead > 0) request.AddRange(BytesRead);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
//result.MimeType = res.ContentType;
//result.LastModified = response.LastModified;
if (!resuming)//(Size == 0)
{
    //resuming = false;
    Size = (int)response.ContentLength;
    SizeInKB = (int)Size / 1024;
}
acceptRanges = String.Compare(response.Headers["Accept-Ranges"], "bytes", true) == 0;

//create network stream
ns = response.GetResponseStream();
```

At the end of the above code, you get a network-stream object which you can then use to read the bytes of the remote file as if you are reading any other stream object. Now, whether the remote url supports resuming partial downloads by allowing you to read from any arbitary position is determined by the **"Accept-Ranges"** HTTP header as shown above. If this value is set to anything other than "bytes", then this feature won't be supported.

In fact, this code is part of a bigger opensource download-manager that I'm trying to implement in C#. You may refer to this application and see if anything can be helpful to you: http://scavenger.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

There is open source .Net http file downloader with automatic resume/retry support (if server supports it), looks like it's exactly what you need, can try to use it:

https://github.com/Avira/.NetFileDownloader .

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: @leonidp All seems good there, but a class DownloadCacheImplementation is missing. Could you please help me out.

Comment: @AmitRanjan here is very simple DownloadCache implementation which stores files in temporary folder and uses ETag to detect that file is modified:    http://pastebin.com/GY7fRER0 . You probably have to tweak it a bit because i did not test it well.

Comment: this link says page not found 404

Comment: may be this https://github.com/captincook/.NetFileDownloader