# make download resumable using c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient

I am using this method (`WebClient` Class) for downloading a file from the Internet :

```
private Task DownloadUpdate(string url, string fileName)
{
       var wc = new WebClient();
       return wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), @"c:\download" + fileName);
}
```

How can I make the download *resumable* using the above code?

Comment: See the Range headers (related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434647/using-the-http-range-header-with-a-range-specifier-other-than-bytes). I'm not sure if WebClient has any standard support for dealing with Range (or the response Content-Range) headers which are required for HTTP downloading resuming - in which case, seek a different library/wrapper :D

Comment: Here is another overview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336203/httpwebrequest-or-webrequest-resume-download-asp-net (I guess WebClient does support basic range wrapping; but you'll still be required to correctly send and handle the range data) and even more of an implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270216/download-large-file-from-http-with-resume-retry-support-in-net .. its amazing what a little searching can do (found via "C# web client resume download").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [HttpWebRequest or WebRequest - Resume Download ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336203/httpwebrequest-or-webrequest-resume-download-asp-net):

> Resuming files is done by specifying the byte range of the file you
>   would like to download using the Range HTTP header. This can be done
>   in .NET with the [`HttpWebRequest.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ds43y3w.aspx) function.

For example:

```
request.AddRange(1000);
```