# Resumable file download request from C# client to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I'm currently just using a simple `WebClient.DownloadFile()` in my C# client to grab large file updates from my webserver (ASP.NET).

Right now, if someone disconnects or restarts their PC, there doesn't seem to be any way to get WebClient to resume the download from where it finished. What's the easiest way to make this download resumable?

(Note that this functionality is embedded in my application, so I don't want to use a third-party download manager)

Comment: it's duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797167/make-download-resumable-using-c-sharp

Comment: the solution is using `request.AddRange(1000);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336203/httpwebrequest-or-webrequest-resume-download-asp-net

Comment: so i'd have to manually track which blocks have been downloaded, manually merge the blocks etc?