# Continue Downloading after network connection reset

Tags: c#, file

While downloading a file from url, if connection lost and reset then my program throwing an exception like

> "unable to read the data from the transport connect: the connection
>   was closed "

this is my code.

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = 
        (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = 
        (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

WebClient client = new WebClient();

//Stream strRemote = client.OpenRead(url);
Stream strRemote = response.GetResponseStream();

FileStream strLocal = 
        new FileStream(sFileSavePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

int iByteSize = 0;
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[8192];

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        iByteSize = strRemote.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
        {
            //some code related to saving into file.                               
        }                         
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Message: " + ex.Message); 
    }
}
```

When the network is continues my code working perfectly. But when I lost the network connection and after connection gets reset my program showing above exception. I want to continue my downloading process after network connection reset. Please help to handle the situation.

Comment: This is not so easy. A connection reset is typically initiated by the server, not caused by a network disruption. Thus, the server will never "continue", but only accept a new request, once it's ready (again)

Comment: k. i can request a new connection. but how to start downloading from where i lost the connection. is there a way to do so.

Comment: This question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270216/download-large-file-from-http-with-resume-retry-support-in-net

Comment: some how i managed to start downloading after connection reset, but i want download file from where it got closed. i am tracking the number of bytes downloaded and the length of the file. please help me.

Comment: While this is a good an valid question, I flagged it as duplicate. See the question mentioned by @Serv

Comment: Finally i solved the problem. This is how i did it, Somehow i got the connection lost event. When connection reset, i sent fresh httpwebrequest with range(start,end). start is the number of bytes downloaded before connection lost and end is total file length( response.ContentLength). This is how i did it and my download got continued. Thank you all for the support.